# Day of week in GWT / Java Date api

Tags: java, date, gwt

How do I get day of week for a given `Date` in `GWT` on client side?

I know I can get it from `Date` object usin `getDay()` but I am not sure if this is the best way.

Is there any alternative?

Is it acceptable & reliable to use deprecated methods of java Date api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("c"); // try with "E" pattern also

String dayOfWeek = format.format(new Date());
System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
```

For more patterns have a look at [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)

output

```
0 for sunday
```

Comment: But this is textual representation, right? I would need also the numeric representation.

Comment: It prints 0 for sunday. try `c` pattern.

Comment: I think I its not properly documented in JavaDoc of `DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: Ok it prints number. The documentation seems wrong. But why is this not affected by locale? I changed 3 different locales (US, GB, Russia), made sure they are set by `getLocaleName()` but still it acts like in my time zone where it is still Saturday.

Comment: Changing locales does not affect the time zone. You need to pass a time zone object to the format() method. Otherwise, it uses the default time zone of your browser.

Comment: @LeNoob Look at this example [gwtDateTime](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwtDateTime)

Comment: Yep, I googled that one as well also found how to format with a given time-zone. But how do I set the default time-zone at the client side?

Comment: Try `TimeZone.setDefault()` and call it from `EntryPointClass#onModuleLoad()` at the very beginning.

Comment: Look at this post [Date Serialization in RPC](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-web-toolkit/serializer$20date$20lust/google-web-toolkit/XDl_P_xOJPo/Rgtr_0BZqaAJ)

Comment: Actually `TimeZone.setDefault()` is `java.util` and is not supported in GWT.

Answer (score 2):

There is no harm in using `getDay()` in GWT code until a better option is available. It's deprecated, but there are no plans to remove this method any time soon.

Comment: what do you think about my post?

Comment: OP asked `Is there any alternative?`

Comment: If I create a `Date` on server and send it via RPC to client. Will be the client's or server's timezone determine the value of day of week?

Comment: I think `DateTimeFormat` uses internationalization and we can use locale also.

Comment: The Date object in Java is timezone-independent. When you print it, however, you need to specify the time zone. The same Date may represent a different day of the week depending on the time zone selected on the client.

Comment: Ok. I was not sure about implementation of `Date`. Whether is just `long` wrapper and all the locale dependent data is done by context at  the time of accessing it's properties or whether it is set on creation. So as I understand, the result of `getDay()` depends on the default time zone at the client side, right?

Answer (score 2):

Use `JsDate.getDay()` it works perfectly well.